# Styling summary tag in HTML

Tags: html

I'm very new to using HTML and recently came across the `details` and `summary` tags. I tried styling the `summary`, but using heading or `<p>` shifted the text away from the arrow.

Specifically, I wanted to make the summary larger, so I used a `<p>` inside the summary. However, this caused the arrow to show above the text - the following code can replicate this

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <p style="font-size:20px">Example</p>
  </summary>
  Inside text
</details>
```

Comment: `summary {font-size: 200px}` - learn CSS, as HTML on it's own is just markup language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**p Tag** is an block element thats what makes the arrow shift to a new line, in order to achieve your diserd result change the **p tag** to inline or use inline element instead such as **span**

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <p style="font-size:20px; display:inline">Example</p>
  </summary>
  Inside text
</details>
```